# Non-Nullable DateTime in SQL Server with EF Code First

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I have a table called Tournaments which is created using the EF code first approach with the following attributes:

```
    public int TournamentID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String DirectorSurname { get; set; }
    public String DirectorFirstName { get; set; }
    public String Logo { get; set; }
    public String Timezone { get; set; }
    public String Telephone { get; set; }
    public String Fax { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Website { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int IntervalTime { get; set; }
```

If I run this and check my SQL Server Management Studio then the StartDate and EndDate gets created but it is non-nullable despite me not adding the [Required] DataAnnotations. How can I fix this?

Comment: By adding Required you state that the value IS Required. It is handled by validation. Telling the model that a field is required will not produce a nullable field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public DateTime? StartDate {get;set;}
public DateTime? EndDate {get;set;}
```

C# nullable types gets converted to SQL nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Nullable` which can define nullable type......